# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements - Selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-junit, selenium4

There is a requirement where I have to add extension in browser before running scripts.
For that I decided to use Browser Options (EdgeOptions).Browser option is introduced in selenium 4.

All required dependencies I have already imported but now I am getting exception in PageFactory.initElements.

- selenium-api-4.1.1
- selenium-chrome-driver-4.1.1
- selenium-chromium-driver-4.1.1
- selenium-edge-driver-4.1.1
- selenium-java-4.1.1
- selenium-remote-driver-4.1.1
- selenium-support-4.1.1

**Do I have to add some other dependencies also?**

```
Message: cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to instantiate class com.proj.stepdefinitions.common.ConfigTestData
at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:40)
at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.getInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:26)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:59)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:222)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:210)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:200)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.DefaultJavaObjectFactory.cacheNewInstance(DefaultJavaObjectFactory.java:34)
    ... 31 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(Lorg/openqa/selenium/WebDriver;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at com.proj.stepdefinitions.common.ConfigTestData.<init>(ConfigTestData.java:115)
        ... 36 more
```

**ConfigTestData code below :**

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import cucumber.api.Scenario;
import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;

import com.step.AfterScenarioScript; //project class


public class ConfigTestData {
    
    //some constants
    
    public static WebDriver driver = null;

    //exception here    
    CommonMethods cm = PageFactory.initElements(driver, 
    CommonMethods.class);

    AfterScenarioScript afterScenarioScript = PageFactory.initElements(driver, AfterScenarioScript.class); 
    
    private CreateFile file = PageFactory.initElements(driver, CreateFile.class);
    
    @Before
    public void init(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
        prop = Login.readPropertiesFile();
        
        
        //some code
    }

     

    @After
    public void afterScenario(Scenario scenario) throws Throwable {
        //some code
    }
    
    //some utility methods
    
}
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Can you show us your `ConfigTestData` class ?

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded **ConfigTestData** code